# Why am I getting this error and what do I need to do: "Error You have tried to access a weblog that does not exist."?

Tags: error, admin

I have created a 'staging' version of my site on a new server.

When I am in the admin area I can see the list of weblog entries just fine, but when I click on one of them to edit it, I receive this error:

```
"Error
You have tried to access a weblog that does not exist."
```

Is this a config or permissions problem? What should I do to fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It maybe worth checking to see if you’ve got the same number of exp_weblog_titles and exp_weblog_data rows.

You can do this by going to Admin > Utilities > SQL Manager > Database Query Form

```
select count(*) as cnt from exp_weblog_titles
select count(*) as cnt from exp_weblog_data
```

Enter these one at a time inside your form. Make sure the numbers match.

Comment: They are different.
select count(*) as cnt from exp_weblog_data returned 1576.
select count(*) as cnt from exp_weblog_titles returned 1706.
So does that mean I should recopy the database?

Comment: I've re-imported the database and am now getting the same count and everything is working. Thank you.